# How to enable camera filechooser from Android Webview?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, camera, filechooser

I am using the following code to let users upload images to a website. This works sort off (Android constantly nags that only the selected files are shared, duh). Now I want to enable the user to use the camera, take a pic, and upload it. Can I adopt my code to enable this? Or what is the right way to do this?

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.ValueCallback
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient
import android.webkit.WebView
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var webView: WebView

    private var fileChooserResultLauncher = createFileChooserResultLauncher()
    private var fileChooserValueCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>? = null


    private fun createFileChooserResultLauncher(): ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> {
        return registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
            if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                fileChooserValueCallback?.onReceiveValue(arrayOf(Uri.parse(it?.data?.dataString)));
            } else {
                fileChooserValueCallback?.onReceiveValue(null)
            }
        }
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val actionBar: ActionBar? = supportActionBar
        actionBar?.hide()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Initialize WebView
        webView = findViewById(R.id.MyWebview)

        // Set up WebView settings
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        webView.settings.useWideViewPort = true
        webView.settings.allowFileAccess = true
        webView.settings.allowContentAccess = true

        // Load your web page
        webView.loadUrl("https://xxxxx?time=" + System.currentTimeMillis())

        webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
            override fun onShowFileChooser(webView: WebView?, filePathCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>?, fileChooserParams: FileChooserParams?): Boolean {
                try {
                    fileChooserValueCallback = filePathCallback;
                    fileChooserResultLauncher.launch(fileChooserParams?.createIntent())
                } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                    // You may handle "No activity found to handle intent" error
                }
                return true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried enabling the permissions and using various solutions mentioned on this site, but to no avail.